# How can I play a song preview in iTunes using Applescript and Java?

Tags: java, applescript, itunes

I've been using the iTunes API frequently to search for songs, and I wanted the user to be able to select an option to play a song preview in iTunes.

Currently, the following will simply open iTunes:

```
public class PlayMedia {

public PlayMedia()
  {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", "tell application \"iTunes\" to play"};

    try
    {
      Process process = runtime.exec(args);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    new PlayMedia();
}
```

How can I expand on this to pass in a song ID/title?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] args = {"osascript", "-e", "on run {arg1, arg2,…}", 
                              "-e", "  tell application \"iTunes\" to …", 
                              "-e", "end run", 
                              "--",
                              arg1, arg2, …};
```

Comment: I would kindly ask you to provide an explanation of your code.

Comment: See `man osascript`. That explains how to pass script arguments.

Comment: @foo This doesn't work, it doesn't even open iTunes, let alone play a song preview.

`public PlayMedia(String title) {
  
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
     String[] args = {"osascript", "-e", "on run {title}", 
             "-e", "  tell application \"iTunes\" to play", 
             "-e", "end run", 
             "--",
             title};
     try
     {
       Process process = runtime.exec(args);
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }`

Comment: Not sure why. What's the error? Try giving the full path to `"/usr/bin/osascript"` in case it's a `$PATH` issue. I don't have a JVM on this machine, but the Python equivalent works fine: `subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", "on run {trackName}", "-e", " tell application \"iTunes\" to play track named trackName", "-e", "end run", "--", title])`.

Comment: @foo

The following doesn't seem to work:

`String[] args = {"osascript", "-e", "on run {Location}", 
             "-e", "  tell application \"iTunes\" to play track named Location", 
             "-e", "end run", 
             "--",
             "Location"};`

Comment: `Location` is a reserved keyword in iTunes so can't be used as an identifier here. Try renaming it to `theLocation`. (Avoiding one-word identifier names greatly reduces the risk of keyword collisions.) It's also a good idea to test your AppleScript code in Script Editor first.